# Filter out distinct elements with condition

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a list of objects that has some duplicates by a property. I would like to get all non-duplicate and also 1 of the duplicates based on a condition.

For eg.

Lists:

1. Code: 1, Grade: 10
2. Code: 1, Grade: 20
3. Code: 2, Grade: 1

Expected List:

1. Code: 1, Grade: 20
2. Code: 2, Grade: 1

The condition would be that of the duplicate elements, grab the one with the highest `Grade`. How would I write the lambda or linq expression to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `GroupBy` to do this:

```
var results = items.GroupBy(item => item.Code)
                   .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(i => i.Grade)
                   .First());
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you first `GroupBy` the `Code` property, and then select the `Max` of each element in the group

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
list.GroupBy(item=>item.Code).Select(item=>new {code = item.Key, grade = item.Max(i=>i.Grade)}).ToList();
```